# Little bit Confuse with RBAC in PHP Article with Sitepoint

Tags: php, security

I'm quit new in PHP and I wanna learn about role based access control systems...

I've not found too much articles related to this but that one I Read (Sitepoint.com's [**RBAC IN PHP**](http://www.sitepoint.com/role-based-access-control-in-php/)) is a great article in one of them.

But I couldn't understand well about **role_name** and **perm_desc** columns.
I mean, what should come in `role_name` and what in `perm_desc` column...

Can you please explain in bit detail...?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Role consist of Admin, Vendor Admin, etc and in Permission it includes parentfoldername.childfoldername.index (e.g. admin.city.index) [here index means index.php]

If you're using MVC then there will be 4 (min) permission:

```
1: parentfoldername.childfoldername.index
2: parentfoldername.childfoldername.create
3: parentfoldername.childfoldername.edit
4: parentfoldername.childfoldername.show
```

In Role-Permission you assign permission to respective roles and if they access those file which are not assigned to them. It will show Access Viloation message. (Ofcourse you have to set that validation)

Comment: but i have to restrict perticuler options inside the page as different user

Comment: In that case you have to check who is the current user and add php if-else condition on the element you want to enable-disable w.r.t. different user.

Comment: yes but in that case what should go in roles and permission??

Comment: If you are giving access to particular element on a page then nothing will go in roles and permission. But when you want to restrict a module to particular roles then above mentioned value will go to roles, permission and role_permission table.